How to use built in assertion on partitioned table that require filter
I have a dataform table my_table which is partitioned by my_column which is required to be used when querying it, I'm trying to define assertion on my_table, for example nonNull but I'm getting:

Cannot query over table 'my_table' without a filter over column(s) 'my_column' that can be used for partition elimination.

which is  normal, my question what is configuration need to be add in order to add a filter to the assertion ?
I once passed by this config but I can't find it anymore, does anyone have an idea?

HI , the error you mentioned Can't query ..... - it's an issue with BigQuery's optimizer. You can follow this google community post  for solution .To add filter you can modify the query. Built-in assertions conditions  nonNull rowConditions . Let me know if this helps or not .

I don't think so, the issue is that I'm using requirePartitionFilter thus everytime i'm quering the table I must add my_column in the where clause, the issue is that when using built in assertions I'm not in control of the where clause

Hi @aName, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

In your assertion ... you seem to be saying "Check that my_table doesn't contain any rows where column  is NULL" (you didn't say which column you were checking).  However, it seems that the admin has said "my_table is so large, I want to prevent someone querying its content without pruning how much is examined".  Remember, if you dont reference the partition filter, you will do a full table scan ... is this really what you want to happen?"
